# Issue when creating category charts in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a table with different columns called  "Bajo conocimiento...", "Exceso de...", etc. Each column has discrete values: 1, 2, 3 or empty (NULL). I need to **count the number of occurrences of 1, 2 and 3 in each of these variables**. 
What I did first was to create bins for each variable. Thus I was able to create a graphic shown below.

[image]

However, the problem is that always one of variables is automatically picked as a filter. In the example below this is "Bajo conocimiento..." (the blue one). So, the values for "Bajo conocimiento..." are correct, however, for instance, the COUNT("Exceso de...") for the values 1, 2 and 3 are the **intersections** of "Exceso de..." with "Bajo conocimiento...". As a result, the values of "Exceso de..." are lower that they should be.

How can I **count the occurrences of 1, 2 and 3 for each variable independently** and get the resulting chart?.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a table calculation for every one of your columns.
Create a calculated field with the following formula and call it eg `[ExcesoCOUNT]`:
`{fixed [columnname]: COUNT([columnname])}`

if you drag the newly created field on your dashboard and turn it into a AVG() rather than a SUM(), you will get the count of each value.

Comment: SO, there should be AVG(ACOUNT),...AVG(DCOUNT) placed into Columns, but what should be defined in Rows and other places?